# Domains not being resolved using public DNS servers after usage of pihole/adguard

Tags: domain-name-system, mac, unifi

I am having issues on a client machine (Mac) accessing different sites, for instance reddit.com, after having used adguard/pihole in my local network on a raspberry pi.

To resolve the issue I thought it would be enough to set the DNS Server to something like `8.8.8.8 (google)` on the wifi interface.

But when doing an `nslookup -debug reddit.com` I still get the following answer:

```
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    reddit.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  reddit.com
    origin = cleanbrowsing.rpz.noc.org
    mail addr = accesspolicy.rpz.noc.org
    serial = 1
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 900
    expire = 1209600
    minimum = 86400
    ttl = 3600
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find reddit.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I have used my pi as pihole server or adguard home server previously on all my client machines in the network due to DHCP DNS configuration.

But now that I hardcode google DNS shouldn't I get the correct authoritative answer from Google DNS? For sure Google DNS knows reddit.com.

Edit:

#### What did I try already?

- I flushed my Mac's DNS caches and just about every DNS cache on my networks machines
- I connected to another network (personal hotspot) - I could resolve reddit.com using 8.8.8.8!

So it seems to have something to do with my network:

Here is my network:

- Unifi Dream Machine SE as router with different networks
- Each network on the UDM has 2 DNS servers set for DHCP: One pointing to a pihole, one to itself

When I connect to a network I automatically get the 2 DNS servers via DHCP config. The intention was to block malicious sites.

While working on that I deactivated the blocking but still couldn't access sites and had adblocking active :/ .

Then I hardcoded the upstream DNS of my machines to Google DNS and still wasn't able to resolve reddit.com.

Now I was puzzled and still am.

Comment: Why did someone downvote without leaving a comment? I am  helpless here and cannot find answer! I flushed every DNS cache I could find in all my network, did everything I could. Still I cannot reach reddit and some other websites in my network.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but have you flushed your DNS cache?

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that. The result looks slightly different, but doesn't help (also I tried this before).
`nslookup -debug reddit.com
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
 reddit.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find reddit.com: NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `dig` or `host`, since OSX is Unix so it comes with `bind` utils, and `nslookup` is old and harder to customize.
That said, directly querying DNS servers with `dig reddit.com` or `host reddit.com` is not using the OS cache: you pass through the cache if you use `ping reddit.com` or `curl https://reddit.com`.
Could it be the Ubuqity device is performing some firewalling to forbid clients setting their own DNS?
To confirm this, you can set the google DNS on the Unify itself.
I would look at pihole logs/configuration, to understand if it is able to resolve itself: if the router is a new addition to the network, and it is filtering DNS queries, it may be also filtering pihole.

Probably [this](https://cleanbrowsing.org/help/docs/disable-content-filtering-on-ubiquiti-dream-machine-pro-udmpro-controller-6-0/) could help

Comment: could you explain what you mean by: „_I would look at pihole logs/configuration, to understand if it is able to resolve itself: if the router is a new addition to the network, and it is filtering DNS queries, it may be also filtering pihole._“? What should be able to resolve itself? And what should I look for exactly when looking at the logs?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear (but I see you figured out, anyway).I meant that probably also the pihole host wasn't able to resolve names, and that you could find out checking pihole logs, for example as explained [here](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-watch-and-interpret-the-pihole-log-file/276)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of @Nicola and also with the help of comments of my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1758217/domains-not-being-resolved-using-public-dns-servers-after-usage-of-pihole-adguar/1758417#1758417) I found the solution to the problem in my networks Unifi UDM SE router: Under "Settings > Networks > [YourNetworkHere] > Advanced: Content Filtering" set the filtering mode to "None", otherwise cleanbrowsing.org will be used for DNS ‍♂️.

Wasn't aware of the real consequences of this setting.

This would explain all the problems.
Thanks for all your help and pointing me in the right direction!